# React 18, reusable state and isMounted

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have been using this code for a while, to cancel API calls, timers actions etc... after a component unmounts.

```
const useIsMounted = (logLabel) => {
  // Normally I would assign true, here assign a random number to track things:
  const isMounted = useRef(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1));

  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (logLabel) logDev(`useIsMounted ${logLabel} mounted id=${isMounted.current}`);

      return (() => {
        if (logLabel) logDev(`useIsMounted ${logLabel} un-mounted id=${isMounted.current}`);
        isMounted.current = false;
      });
    },
    [logLabel],
  );

  return isMounted;
};
```

In normal cases, logLabel is not defined, I use it only in case such as... today :-)

I will then call this hook anywhere I need to cancel things if a component unmounts:

```
const isMountedRef = useIsMounted('blah');

// Then later on, for example in some API async call result:

  ...
  if (isMountedRef.current) {
    // do something with the result
  } else {
    // drop the result
  }
```

With React 18, in strict mode, this is broken. This hook preserve the 'false' value it got on the first unmount, in my logs:

```
useIsMounted blah mounted id=9005
....
useIsMounted blah un-mounted id=9005
...
useIsMounted blah mounted id=false
```

I don't really see how to fix this. Further I have the feeling that using this hook is going at it wrong with React 18, but I don't see really how to manage this type of issue properly.

Any comment, suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just after posting this, I found a link to the react-use library's [useMountedState](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/src/useMountedState.ts) hook.

I does what I'm trying to do, but it does it right :-)

The key is to set the ref value in the useEffect, not in its initialization:

```
const useIsMounted = (logLabel) => {
  const isMounted = useRef();

  useEffect(
    () => {
      isMounted.current = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);

      if (logLabel) logDev(`useIsMounted ${logLabel} mounted id=${isMounted.current}`);

      return (() => {
        if (logLabel) logDev(`useIsMounted ${logLabel} un-mounted id=${isMounted.current}`);
        isMounted.current = false;
      });
    },
    [logLabel],
  );

  return isMounted;
};
```

This fixed it for me!